# What is this plant, and is it worth saving

Tags: identification, shrubs

My well meaning father-in-law transplanted this plant into our flower bed, thinking it was a rose bush.  So far (2 years) we haven't seen any flowers.  It has some pretty serious thorns and is kind of growing wild, reaching out of the flower bed.  Therefore, I'm inclined to remove it, but before doing so I thought it would be a good idea to properly identify it and find out if it has potential to be a nice plant.  If you recognize this plant, or can lead me into the right direction, I would appreciate it.
Thanks

[image]
[image]
 [image]

Comment: It's sort-of a rose... Could be mulitflora rose (which is more of a noxious weed from the rose family) - used to be thought of as a great erosion-control plant, but it's just downright nasty and invasive, so less-well-though-of-these days. If it's that, the flowers are small, dull, and fleeting - it's not from the nicer side of the family at all.

Comment: Some quick reading on multiflora rose suggests that it really shouldn't be in my flower bed.  Aside from the invasiveness, it's described to have stems in the 10 - 15 feet long.  Way too big.

Comment: Huge, bloodthirsty tangles. I've been fighting some for many a year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm very sure this is a wild rose.  Yes they can be invasive, but rather than just dumping it you might think about putting it in an attractive large pot and keep it.  They have the most delightful 5 petal blossom.  Most always a light pink, and the rose hips, though small, if saved can make an impressive and delicious herb tea. The other added benefit is that when they bloom when you water, or it rains their fragrance is  intoxicating.